# How to ignore JS errors in Selenium with PhantomJS?

Tags: selenium, phantomjs

I am working with a page that has some JS errors like `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'q.apply(m,d)')`, browsers seem to ignore these errors and the page functionality doesn't degrade, but PhantomJS throws an exception. How can I disable that? I've read [how to ignore errors in phantomjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19459247/how-to-ignore-errors-in-phantomjs) but I don't know how to do that with Selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run my tests using PhantomJS 2.0 then I do not get the non-fatal javascript errors getting reported.  However when I run with PhantomJS version 1.9.8 then I get the exact behavior that you describe.  So simply upgrading the version of PhantomJS you are using to the latest may solve your problem.

Otherwise you can change the logging level of PhantomJS.  I believe you can use code like this below where you instantiate the browser.

```
    DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    caps.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
    caps.setCapability(PhantomJSDriverService.PHANTOMJS_CLI_ARGS, "--webdriver-loglevel=ERROR");
    WebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(caps);
```

Comment: I don't think the loglevel matters. About the version you are right, I was using 1.9, I'm investigating what is happening with 2.0.

Comment: In the release notes it says "...switches the core implementation to use Qt 5 to get a more modern base platform, as well as to have an updated WebKit module."  I suspect that the underlying JavaScript engine has undergone a major change.