# Running phantomjs on a website with broken javascript

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am trying to run phantomjs to crawl a website with broken javascript therefore I am getting errors when running phantomjs through my CLI.

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: facebook
```

The website itself show the error like this through the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: facebook is not defined
```

It seems to stop any further execution of phantomjs. Is there any way to ignore the error and continue with execution of phantomjs?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/19538646/1781026 & https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10042#issuecomment-95668850

Comment: Still seems to freeze, besides that the phantomjs project seems dead as well. Doubt I will continue this. https://www.infoq.com/news/2017/04/Phantomjs-future-uncertain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phantomjs project seems to be dead in the water since chrome is capable of headless browsing and it will therefore be disbanded. The error handling won't resolve my issue so I switched to http://www.nightmarejs.org/.

Seems like an amazing alternative which can even show you what happens by using a live example and the commands you have provided.